# “This video was recorded with a sandwich”

Tags: humor

It is a top comment from [this youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FhzVTB8ryQM). I'm sure it is a way of expressing sense of humor, but I just can't get it. My guess is that they are just saying the video is just as short as the time it takes to make a sandwich.

Comment: I would guess it's more likely a comment on the recording quality, or simply somebody being absurd. Unless there's a sandwich meme I don't know about.

Comment: absurd combinations, like lunch meat and peanut butter, can be humorous - or just taste bad. :-P  Or, perhaps, it is quite literal, a comment from the sound or video recording engineer who was eating his sandwich at the time.  (This comment typed with ice cream :)

Comment: @HowardPautz We should begin recording video with ice cream so video quality can be expected as good as your comment :)

Comment: @TerryLi speaking of sandwiches, we have to be careful with technology mixed with deserts or especially with beverages - even nonalcoholic drinks can spell humorous disasters, like this: http://snltranscripts.jt.org/78/78ppepsi.phtml

Comment: @TerryLi, I hope you're not simply trying to FowardTheWord. Because there are two more yt videos with that phrase featured prominently, and they're made 5 year after the 1M+ views video in the op. Sorry, but it looks to me like an attempt at meme creation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The comment refers to the poor video quality (240p).

However, the joke most commonly used *potato* instead of *sandwich*.

More on this joke: http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/recorded-with-a-potato

Comment: Yeah, there you go! I knew the sandwich reminded me of some meme, but I couldn't quite pinpoint it. Talking about an unbidden memory...
It's funny, I bust my gut again even though I had laughed it back to the forrests of my mind.

Comment: The meme is also a descendent of the ["Sent from my x"](http://www.theatlantic.com/technology/archive/2013/07/mobile-device-email-signatures-more-than-you-ever-wanted-to-know/277950/) mobile email/chat [signature gag](http://www.ign.com/boards/threads/what-is-this-sent-from-my-insert-name-of-budget-phone-using-tapatalk-joke.250051187/).

Answer (score 2):

I'd say he is either referring to the poor video quality or just trying to create humor out of randomness. In my opinion it is probably the latter.

Comment: The video is horrible quality and sandwiches make inadequate recording devices.